# Esconder Div após x segundos apos executar acao

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Bom dia Galera,

Tenho em minha home , um campo para consultar CPF. O campo tem apenas um campo texto , onde informo o CPF, se encontrar algum cpf no banco , ele me retorna alguns dados.Eu submeto o formulario com ajax , para nao recarregar a pagina , na pagina que faz a consulta , eu jogo os dados em um array e o converto para json , recupero o valor na minha home e imprimo eles.

A div que mostrara os dados , eu a deixo oculta: `<style>style:display:none;</style>`
Quando eu pressiono o botao para pesquisar , ele exibe uma tabela com os dados :

```
    <script>
$("#btnConsulta").click
    (
        function()
            {
                var show =  $("#divForm").css("display","block");
            }
    );
</script>
```

ate ai blz. Mas eu gostaria que a div com essa tabela fosse ocultada novamente  ,apos x segundos.

fix o codigo :

```
function hideDiv()
            {
                $("#divForm").css("display","none");
            }
```

E usei o setInterval para executar ele após x segundos. Mas se eu defino que ira chamar a funçao de esconder em 10 segundos , se eu entrar na pagina  , esperar 5 segundos e pesquisar , a minha div so ficara visivel por mais 5 .

Eu gostaria que o setInterval começasse a contar após eu pressionar o botao de pesquisar.

EDIT :----------

Codigo que uso para submeter o formulario e pegar os dados.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function consultaCpf()
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#form1').submit(
        function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax
                (
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/admin2/inc/ajaxSubmit/consultaCpf.php",
                        data: dados,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(json)
                        {
                            $('#nomeVendedor').html( json.vendedor);
                            $('#nomeCliente').html( json.cliente );
                            $('#cpfCliente').html( json.cpf );
                        }
                    }
                );

                return false;
            });
        });
    }

consultaCpf();
</script>
```

Aqui ele manda o formulario para a pagina consultaCpf.php.

Na pagina consultaCpf.php :

```
$return = array();
$cpf = $_POST['txtCpf'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vendedor,nomeCliente,cpf
 FROM tblVenda where cpf = '$cpf' ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      { 
            $vendedor = $row['vendedor'];
            $cliente = $row['nomeCliente'];
            $cpf2 = $row['cpf'];
      }
$return['vendedor'] = $vendedor;
$return['cliente'] = $cliente;
$return['cpf'] = $cpf2;

echo json_encode($return);
```

---

Desde ja , grato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que você quer algo nessa linha aqui:

```
updateDiv = (function () {
    var currentTimeout = null;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    return function (divContent) {
        myDiv.textContent = divContent;
        if (currentTimeout !== null) {
            clearTimeout(currentTimeout); }
        currentTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            currentTimeout = null;
            hideDiv();
        }, 10000);
    };
})();
```

Aí você usaria `updateDiv` como o callback do seu AJAX: não só eu disparo o `setTimeout` só quando a resposta volta (evitando o problema que você mencionou), mas se o usuário fizer outra consulta nesse intervalo de 10 segundos, eu cancelo o timeout anterior (se você não fizer isso, a segunda consulta vai ser ser fechada 10 segundos depois da *primeira* consulta).

---

**Editado:** no código que você colocou: você declararia uma variável global logo depois de abrir o `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTimeout = null;
    function consultaCpf()
    {
        …
```

…e no `jQuery.ajax` você faria

```
success: function(json)
{
    $('#nomeVendedor').html( json.vendedor);
    $('#nomeCliente').html( json.cliente );
    $('#cpfCliente').html( json.cpf );
    if (currentTimeout !== null) {
        clearTimeout(currentTimeout); }
    currentTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        currentTimeout = null;
        hideDiv();
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Bom dia ctgPi , como assim usa-la como call back  ? Poderia dar um exemplo de como ficaria ? Grato

Comment: Como você está fazendo o AJAX? Na unha, com jQuery? Edita a sua pergunta pra colocar o javascript que dispara o AJAX pra eu poder dar o exemplo.

Comment: Entendi . Testei e funcionou.  Vlw

Answer (score 4):

Quem vai te ajudar aqui é o [setTimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/). De maneira simples, você pode fazer:

```
$("#btnConsulta").on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#divForm").css("display","none");
    }, 5000);  
});
```

Basicamente, a `#divForm` vai sumir 5 segundos depois que `#btnConsulta` for clicado.

**EDIT:**

Demorei um pouco pra entender o seu objetivo mas, depois da conversa nos comentários, cheguei lá. O código final fica:

```
$("#btnConsulta").on('click', function(){
    $("#divForm").css("display","block");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#divForm").css("display","none");
    }, 5000);  
});
```

Vale lembrar que, inicialmente, `#divForm` deve ter `display:none`. Ao clicar em `#btnConsulta`, `#divForm` é imediatamente mostrada, e escondida novamente após 5 segundos.

**EDIT ²:**

Como mencionado pelo @ctgPi, essa solução é bugada. Caso o usuário seja bem loco e clique no botão várias vezes, o *timing* para de funcionar. Um workaround nesse caso seria esconder o botão durante os mesmos 5 segundos que `#divForm` aparece, mas isso talvez não seja tão eficiente.

Comment: `setTimeout` != `setInterval`

Comment: Bom dia Caio , tentei usar seu codigo , mas a div nao chegou a ser exibida.

Comment: Verdade, mals pela confusão ^^

Comment: @re22 Acontece.

Comment: @HenriqueFelix é isso aqui que você quer fazer? http://jsfiddle.net/wqyvpru3/1/

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira  , exatamente !  Acessei o link acima , e testei aqui e funcionou . Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta então

Comment: Essa solução tem o bug que eu mencionei na minha resposta — experimenta clicar o botão várias vezes, espera o div desaparecer, e depois clica o botão de novo — o div vai fechar em menos de 5 segundos.

Comment: @ctgPi verdade.

Comment: Vish , testei e fica bugado o negocio. Mas as consultas que o pessoal aqui faz é bem pouca . O codigo do @ctgPi , vou usa-lo em uma pagina que faço atualizaçao constante  , e estava recebendo este problema. A pagina atualiza os valores com um botao ,mas o setinterval atualizava automaticamente tbm . Assim , nao gasto muito recurso , se apertei o botao ,ele conta mais 15 segudnso para atualizar  .

Comment: Se a resposta do @ctgPi lhe foi útil, marque-a como correta!